# ¿Cuándo se usa "le" en una oración?

Tags: traducción, objetos-indirectos

Estoy aprendiendo sobre objectos indirectos y directos. Yo entiendo cuándo usar *me, se,* y *te*, pero no entiendo *le*.

Un ejemplo:

> Give the book to your sister!
>   Dáselo.

Que es un ejemplo en el que yo usaría *le.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Estás casi en lo correcto.

Si bien en tu ejemplo lo normal sería decir:

> Dálelo.*            (incorrecto)

es incorrecto porque en español existe una regla que dice que cuando se tiene la combinación `le` + `lo`, o `les` + `lo`, se convierten en `selo`:

```
le + lo    ==>   selo
les + lo   ==>   selo
```

Esta transformación también opera en el caso de pronombres no enclíticos (no usados como sufijos):

> Traté de decirle algo a ella.      (I tried to tell her something)
>
> **Le** traté de decir algo.
>
> **Se** lo traté de decir.

Recuerda que lo que se evita decir es **lelo** o **lela**.

Comment: Jamás había leído *dálelo*, ¿es correcto? ¿Dónde se encuentra esta forma?

Comment: Jamás se encuentra, pues es incorrecta. Por ello es que se hace la transformación a "selo".

Comment: Es que dices que *lo normal sería decir*, y para mí, no es normal en lo absoluto.

Comment: Digo *sería* por cuanto ahí correspondería usar `le`.

Comment: What would the two sentences: "Le traté de decor also" and "se lo tart de decir" be translated to in English. This would help me to further understand the differences between le and se and how and when they are used in a sentence.

Comment: @sbswim I am not sure how one could build two different sentences from the original one (all of them with the same meaning), as we do in Spanish.

Comment: Right,but can you provide me with the translations for those two examples you mentioned? Thanks.

Comment: I've just added a translation for the first example. In my opinion (I'm a native Spanish speaker, not an English one), I cannot get another (an equivalent) translation for the other two sentences.

Answer (score 4):

Cuando el pronombre desempeña la función de complemento directo, deben usarse las formas lo, los para el masculino (singular y plural, respectivamente) y la, las para el femenino (singular y plural, respectivamente):

- ¿Has visto a Juan? Sí, lo vi ayer.
- ¿Has visto a Juan y a los niños? Sí, los he visto en el parque.
- Compré la medicina y se la di sin que
  nadie me viera.
- ¿Has recogido a las niñas? Sí, las recogí antes
  de ir al taller.

Cuando el pronombre desempeña la función de complemento indirecto, deben usarse las formas le, les (singular y plural, respectivamente), con independencia del género de la palabra a la que se refiera el pronombre:

- Le pedí disculpas a mi madre.
- Le dije a su hermana que viniera.
- Les di un regalo a los niños.

Echa un vistazo a [este link](http://mimosa.pntic.mec.es/ajuan3/lengua/usosdese.htm) para entender mejor el funcionamiento de los otros pronombres.

También, ten cuidado de cometer los errores conocidos como [laísmo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La%C3%ADsmo)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que *le* como pronombre átono directo se considera válido y parte de la norma culta (si bien no figura en el habla de todos los hablantes) para, según dialecto, referir a personas animadas masculinas singulares, y también (en el llamado *leísmo de cortesía*) para referirse a personas con tratamiento formal.

Comment: gracias por el apunte :)